# Defining custom sectioning commands

Tags: sectioning, hyperref

In a document of mine (`scrbook` class) I have to describe several different scenarios as part of a subsection. I originally used `\subsubsection` for each which are not numbered with the default setting of `secnumdepth`. I could change that counter but having something `1.2.3.1` for a scenario would not look good. 
A problem is that I can't proper `\ref`erence a specific scenario like this because the `\label` would point to the parent `\subsection`. Using a `enumerate` environment isn't really an option here as well.

I would now define a sectioning-like macro `\scenario` which

- Is formatted like `\subsubsection*` of the used class (`scrbook` in my case).
- Starts with `Scenario \thescenario:~`, where `\thescenario` would be a single integer (1, 2, ...) independent of the parent section numbers.
- Can be `\label`ed and referenced correctly using `hyperref`s `\autoref`.

My first approach was the following:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcounter{scenario}
\newcommand{\scenarioautorefname}{scenario}
\newcommand{\scenario}[1]{%
   \refstepcounter{scenario}%
   \subsubsection*{Scenario~\thescenario: #1}%
   %\refstepcounter{scenario}%
}%

\begin{document}
\chapter{MWE}
\section{Grandparent}
\subsection{Parent}
\scenario{Foo}\label{sce:foo}
...
\scenario{Bar}\label{sce:bar}
...
In \autoref{sce:foo} ...
\end{document}
```

This gives me the format of `\subsubsection*`, but the issue is that it interferes with the `\refstepcounter`. If I put `\refstepcounter{scenario}` before it, the scenario number is correct but the `\autoref` will use `subsubsection` not `scenario` for the reference. If I put it at the end of the macro the reference name is correct but the number is off by one, i.e. one to low. Setting the number initially to 1 gives my the correct number in the `\scenario` line and the correct name in `\autoref` but there the number is off by one again, this time one to high.

How can I define such a sectioning-like macro? I personally wouldn't mind using Koma-Script macros to do so, but would welcome a class-independent solution more.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

One possible solution using `titlesec` (to define a new seccional unit for the "Scenarios"), and `hyperref`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\titleclass{\scenario}{straight}[\chapter]
\newcounter{scenario}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\titleformat{\scenario}
  {\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries}{}{0em}{Scenario \thescenario:~}
\titlespacing*{\scenario}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\newcommand{\scenarioautorefname}{scenario}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{MWE}
\section{Grandparent}
\subsection{Parent}
\scenario{Foo}\label{sce:foo}
\scenario{Bar}\label{sce:bar}
...
In \autoref{sce:foo} ...
In \autoref{sce:bar} ...

\end{document}
```

EDIT: As Martin Scharrer mentions in the comments, with these settings each `scenario` has also an associated  PDF bookmark at the chapter level. To control the level of the bookmarks it's enough to define `\toclevel@scenario` to have the appropriate value (e.g., the depth of the desired sectional unit for the bookmark).

To set the scenario toc depth, it's necessary to define `\l@scenario`, which will control the actual typesetting of the entries in the ToC.

As an example, to force `scenario` to behave as a subsubsection in both the ToC (no entry, unless the value of `tocdepth` is set to 3 or greater) and in the PDF bookmarks (no bookmark), something like the following lines of code need to be added to the example code above:

```
\makeatletter
  \def\toclevel@scenario{3}
  \def\l@scenario{\@dottedtocline{3}{3.8em}{3.2em}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to keep the normal `\subsubsection` around. My goal is to define a new sectioning command which inherits its format.

Comment: @Gonzalo: It seems that `\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\arabic{subsubsection}}` is redundant, because this redefinition is already done by the non-starred version of `\counterwithout`.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: I added a new version of the code; this time I defined a new sectional unit, thus keeping the standard `\subsubsection`. @lockstep: you're right. Anyway, I changed my code to satisfy the requirement in Martin's comment.

Comment: @Gonzalo: In the revised version of your example, `\renewcommand{\thescenario}{\arabic{scenario}}` seems to be redundant.

Comment: This should do it. However, it is a pity that the format and spacing can't be copying from `\subsubsection` directly, but must be stated explicitly.

Comment: This works fine so far, however each scenario is also added as PDF bookmark on the highest level (chapter) where it of course doesn't belong. I would like to either have no PDF bookmarks or them on the subsubsection (or similar) level. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: After looking up the source code of `hyperref` I figured to use `\def\toclevel@scenario{4}` which seems to do it.

Comment: Any idea how to avoid that the custom sectioning command is part of the ToC, i.e. can I set it's toc depth so that a low enough `\tocdepth` removes it?

Comment: Found it: A `\l@scenario` macro must be defined, e.g. to `\@dottedtocline {3}{3.8em}{3.2em}` (taken from subsubsection) to draw the dotted line if the `tocdepth` is not lower than the first argument (here: 3).

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: I was just about to answer you. I'm glad that you found the answer.

Comment: You might want to add the `\toclevel@scenario` and `\l@scenario` macros from my comments to the answer, so that it is complete and more useful for other people. Thanks again.

Comment: Only the first three letters are required, so even `@Mar` would work, but I would prefer `@Martin` :-). However, you need more letters if there are more than two people in that comment thread which names start with `Mar`.