# How do you modify LaTeX's sectioning hierarchy?

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents

I am trying to create a new command, so I could use a new hierarchy level in a book document class.

The table of Contents should look like this:

> ## Part I
>
> ### Theme I
>
> #### 1. Chapter 1
>
> #### 2. Chapter 2
>
> 2.1 Section 1
>
> 2.1.1 Subsection
>
> ### Theme II
>
> #### 1. Chapter 1### and so on.

I guess I have to use `\newcommand`, but I don't know how to modify the hierarchy number to include "Theme" between "Part" and "Chapter". If you know a document class with a more complete hierachy than books and implementing a similar hierarchy, it will solve my problem as well.

Comment: Have a look into this question: [Defining custom sectioning commands](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17275/defining-custom-sectioning-commands), this looks like similar to what you want.

Comment: Are you sure you want to cross reference your chapters like "in chapter 2 of theme 1 in part 3"?

Comment: As @egreg points out, even when you use `part` division, the `chapter` counter is not reset with each part, to make the document easily searchable. This is a generally recommended way. Of course this is the case when chapters are usually more than ~10 pages long. If they are not, consider stepping one level down, i.e., changing `section->subsection` and `chapter->section`, and then just rename "Chapter" to "Theme".

Comment: What is your definition of a "Theme"?

Comment: The `memoir` class has a `\book` division over `\part`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with the `memoir` class, that features a document subdivision above "part":

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\renewcommand{\bookname}{Part}
\renewcommand{\partname}{Theme}
\setlength{\cftpartnumwidth}{2em} % set the width of numbers

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents*

\mainmatter
\book{Part 1}
\part{Theme 1}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\chapter{Chapter 2}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection}

\part{Theme 2}

\chapter{Chapter 3}
\chapter{Chapter 4}

\book{Part 2}
\part{Theme 1}
\chapter{Chapter 5}
\chapter{Chapter 6}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection}

\part{Theme 2}

\chapter{Chapter 7}
\chapter{Chapter 8}
\end{document}
```

The class has powerful customization commands.

[image]

I would avoid restarting the numbering of chapters for each "part" or "theme": cross references would be very cumbersome. Something like

> as we saw in Chapter 3 of Theme I in Part II

is really heavy.