# How can I exclude a custom sectioning command from the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, titlesec, tocloft

## Question

How can I exclude a custom titling command (sectioning command) from the table of contents? *Note that I do not want to simply inherit the `\paragraph`, because it is reserved for and extra deeper layer of sectioning.*

## Example

I would like to create a section called `\minisec` with `titlesec`, that is

- numbered, yet does not show the number (for possible future decisions regarding numbering).
- It does not show up in the table of contents.
- It is lower than `\paragraph`

## Sample Code

```
\titleclass{\minisec}{straight}[\paragraph]
\newcounter{minisec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\titleformat{\minisec}[hang]{\normalsize\bfseries}{}{0pt}{#1}
\titlespacing*{\minisec}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\newcommand{\minisecautorefname}{minisec}
```

I adapted this code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17278/13552

Comment: Whether `\titleclass{\minisec}{straight}[\paragraph]
\newcounter{minisec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\titleformat{name=\minisec,numberless}[hang]{\normalsize\bfseries}{}{0pt}{#1}
\titlespacing*{\minisec}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}` is OK for you?

Comment: That causes an error !Missing number, treated as zero. `\minisec{Presettings}`. Could that have something to do with the fact that I am using the `explicit` option in `titlesec`?

Comment: You should use `\minisec*{Presettings}` Note the star.

Comment: Ok, I found the problem and it is just caused by the `setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}`. Using starred commands are not an option for me. Also, my `\paragraph` has been reassigned to work like a `\subsubsubsection`, so the code you provided will not work.

Comment: KOMA-script provides a command `minisec` by default ;-)

Comment: @macmadness86 You didn't mention before that you have `\subsubsubsection`, so how could we have guessed that? Please, instead of just useless snippets, add to your question a *complete*, yet minimal, document showing (only) the relevant settings related to your question.

Comment: Thanks Johannes, I know that it is, but I am switching from KOMA-script and I need a substitute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following example addresses all three questions (the code includes comments):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\titleclass{\minisec}{straight}[\paragraph]

\newcounter{minisec}

% Change 0pt to a positive value once the representation for the counter has been established
\titleformat{\minisec}[hang]
  {\normalsize\bfseries}{\theminisec}{0pt}{#1}
\titlespacing*{\minisec}
  {0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\newcommand{\minisecautorefname}{minisec}

% minisecs will be numebered
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
% minisecs won't appear in the ToC
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

% Provisional empty definition for the counter representation
\renewcommand\theminisec{}

% Settings for the bookmarks and the ToC entries (change the second 
% and third arguments of \@dottedtocline if minisecs should go to the ToC)
\makeatletter
  \def\toclevel@minisec{5}
  \def\l@minisec{\@dottedtocline{5}{3.8em}{3.2em}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{A test section}
In \autoref{sec:minitest} we have an example of
\subsection{A test subsection}
\subsubsection{A test subsubsection}
\paragraph{A test paragraph}
\minisec{A test minisec}
\label{sec:minitest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for such a thorough answer that explains each part! Very helpful :)