# Automatically reset the counter of a custom-defined sectioning block with titlesec

Tags: numbering, counters, titlesec, automation

I added a custom sectioning block to my document following the instructions I found on this question: [Defining custom sectioning commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17275/defining-custom-sectioning-commands). Below is a mvce:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
    % Define a new \question sectioning element
    \titleclass{\question}{straight}[\section]
        \newcounter{question}
    \titleformat{\question}[runin]{\normalfont\bfseries}{QUESTION \thesection .\thequestion:}{0.5em}{}
    \titlespacing*{\question}{0pt}{1ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2ex plus .2ex}
    \newcommand{\questionautorefname}{question}

\begin{document}

\section{The First Section}
\question{} Who am I?
\question{} Who are you?

\section{The Second Section}
\question{} Who are we?
\question{} Who are they?

\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image: Counter sectioning mvce]

Now I am wondering if there's a way to automatically reset the counter after I declare the section so to display `Question 2.1` as opposed to `Question 2.3`, without having to call `\resetcounter{}` manually each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some ways to achieve this:

`\newcounter{question}[section]`  will solve all troubles most likely, however. (Too easy?)

If this is not possible, you can use the package `chngcntr` for this and hook the `question` counter into the `section` counter reset list with

`\counterwithin*{question}{section}`

since you are using the output already as `\thesection .\thequestion`, so you need `\counterwithin*{...}{...}` instead of `\counterwithin{...}{...}`

Alternatively use the LaTeX core command `\@addtoreset`

```
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{question}{section}
\makeatother
```

in the preamble. You don't need the `chngcntr` package then.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{chngcntr}


\usepackage{titlesec}
    % Define a new \question sectioning element
    \titleclass{\question}{straight}[\section]
        \newcounter{question}
    \titleformat{\question}[runin]{\normalfont\bfseries}{QUESTION \thesection .\thequestion:}{0.5em}{}
    \titlespacing*{\question}{0pt}{1ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2ex plus .2ex}
    \newcommand{\questionautorefname}{question}

\counterwithin*{question}{section}

\begin{document}

\section{The First Section}
\question{} Who am I?
\question{} Who are you?

\section{The Second Section}
\question{} Who are we?
\question{} Who are they?

\end{document}
```

[image]